# How to pass data to api using httpclient post method

Tags: angular, http, post, client, angular7

Iam trying to pass data to api using httpclient post method, but in the api only empty array is passed

```
insert_data(input){
this.httpClient.post('http://localhost/tasker/api/index.php/insert_users', {
        data:input,
        tt:'tt'
      }).subscribe();

  }
```

In input the data is available

The api is like this

```
public function insert_users(){
    $input=$this->input->post();
    print_r($input);
}
```

Comment: Please give more context, as such it is not possible to know what's wrong (what's your input, what's your API? what request do you see when you execute the code? and so on). Also, please tell what you tried so far, to help people pinpoint where to lead you. It will greatly help to give you the right answer. Good luck!

Comment: In button click i will call this function  in the componenet.ts. In form.value the data is passed                                                                                  register(form){
   this.service.insert_data(form.value);
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change your code to this

```js
insert_data(input){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };

    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost/tasker/api/index.php/insert_users', 
          {
            data:input,
            tt:'tt'
          }, httpOptions);

      }
}
```

Post method don't need to subscribe. You have to subscribe in the service your call like

```js
    return this.insertDataService.inputData.subscribe();
```

Please let me know if you still have problem

Comment: I tried this but when i click the submit button the api is not called.

Comment: Please upload your full source code in your question so I can take a look

Comment: $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);    I tried this , its working now. what is the use of this

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php. You submit json format data into server so you need to parse in your php server